# (Need Help) Summation in inequalities problem

Tags: inequality, summation

I have an inequalities equation that looks like:

$$\sum_{B=1}^n B (\frac{e}{4})^\frac{B}{2} \ge 1$$

Is it possible to solve for **n**, where n is the upper bound of B (a constant).

I'm currently trying to solve using partial sum series (see below), but it doesn't lead me anywhere after I expanded it.

$$\frac{n(n+1)}{2} (\frac{e}{4})^\frac{B}{2} \ge 1$$

Comment: Please clarify this.  What does "$n$ is the maximum bound of $B$" mean?  Isn't $B$ a constant?  What exactly is the condition on $n$?

Comment: @saulspatz edited. B is a constant that always be substituted with 1,2,3, ... so I need to find the value of n. There is no condition on n.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misread the formula the first time.  If there's one value of $n$ that makes the sum $\ge 1,$ tehn any larger $n$ works also.  Do you want the smallest one?

Comment: @saulspatz sorry for the late reply. But, yes! I want to find the smallest one.

Comment: Chris Custer's answer does just that.

Comment: @saulspatz n >= 2, right? Okay thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $n\ge 2$, the third term is $2(\frac e4)^{\frac22}=\frac e2\gt 1$.

For $n=1$, you get $(\frac e4)^{\frac12}\lt 1$...  so it's false...